# Can't find my android phone via bluetoothctl scan on

Tags: raspbian, python, bluetooth, pi-zero-w, android

I am currently working on a project that fetches the RSSI of my Samsung Galaxy S8 phone via bluetooth on a Raspberry Pi Zero W. I am running Raspbian and have successfully found other devices via

```
bluetoothctl scan on
```

But have yet to find my phone. I got the bluetooth MAC address on my phone but the Raspberry pi can't seem to find it. Any help?

Comment: `have successfully found other devices` .... then why are you posting a question here?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to RPi SE. Unfortunately, I don't have an answer for your question. Many good bluetooth questions get asked here, but there are fewer good answers. I've no expertise or knowledge on bluetooth, but in my own experience, bluetooth on the RPi is a bit dodgy. I don't know why this is: hardware? software? both? Not trying to be negative, but set your expectations. If you perform a search on RPi (at the top of this page), you'll see yours is the 606th question asked here with that tag.

Comment: Is your phone in "discoverable" mode when you run the scan on the Raspberry pi? On Android, it says "visible to other devices". Just to confirm, when you `bluetoothctl devcies` your phone isn't there already?